# How can I change the width of a webpage?

Tags: browser, website

The zoom feature of the browser changes both height and width of a web page. I find some webpages hard to read because of how wide they are onmy screen. [See eg](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/kafka/verwandl/verwandl.html). How would I resize width to be less, so the text breaks around the width that it does on Stackexchange?

Comment: much of the time this is determined by how the website is designed. there won't be a universal answer. HTML by default fills the available width, and only pushes content down when either the available width is insufficient, or the end of a block element is reached. it can be "styled" and structured to provide the kinds of layouts you are describing, but that is up to the site developers. SE sites use a fixed width to present their multi-column layout, and use responsible libraries to control how the page is displayed on radically different screen widths.

Answer (score 1):

Just resize the browser window. The text will flow and accomodate to the new width.

Comment: Many websites are not programmed to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of the web page using your browser's developer tools.

For example, with Firefox/Chromium (there's not really a difference for this), to change the page width for your example URL:

1. Hit `F12` or select *Inspect* in the web page's right click menu.
2. This will open the developer tool window on your right side or bottom side of the browser window. And you should be viewing the *Inspector* (Firefox) or *Elements* (Chromium) tool. (If not, switch to it in the top bar of developer tools.)
3. Selector the `body` element in the *Inspector/Elements* tool.
4. In the right panel, add a CSS rule for this element. The rule should be like `width: 50em`. `50em` means the width of 50 m letters. You should adjust the number to your liking.
5. Hit `F12` again or use the *close* botton to close developer tools and voila.

Below is a screenshot of developer tools with places to be interacted highlighted, in case you are not familiar with it. It's from Firfex but is almost exactly the same for Chromium.

[Developer tools with places to change highlighted (not enough reputation to show the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De5xn.png)